# Problem with chain rule

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

$z=x^2*f(\frac{y}{x^2})$, $f$ is differentiable.
Show that $z$ satisfies the equation $x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+2y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=2z$.

How should i use the chain rule over this?

Comment: Recall the partial chain rule: $\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial U}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$. So what is $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$, if we apply these to $x^2 f[y/x^2] \implies \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[x^2]*\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f[y/x^2]*\frac{\partial }{\partial x}[y/x^2]$

Answer (score 1):

Recall the partial chain rule: $$\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial U}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$$. So what is $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$$ and $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$, if we apply these to $$z=x^2 f(y/x^2) \implies \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2)f(y/x^2)+x^2\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(y/x^2)\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(y/x^2)= x^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(u)*\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(u)+2x f(u)=2x f(u) +\frac{-2 x^2 y}{x^3}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(u)=2x(\frac{-y}{x^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(u)+f(u))=2x((-u)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(u)+f(u)$$ where $u=u(x,y)=\frac{y}{x^2}$

Now repeat with $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}$